# Error: could not find function "read.csv2" Execution halted

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server

I'm trying to install Shiny in RStudio-server but there is an error while installing:

> Error: could not find function "read.csv2"
>   Execution halted

Is a R version problem? I did R.Version() and I got that it is: 3.3.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv2` is a function from the library `utils`. Maybe you have an outdated version.

Have you tried?

`install.packages("utils")
 install.packages("shiny", dependencies=T)`

Best,

Comment: I have tried it but I got the same error. In fact, I got this error (Error: could not find function "read.csv2" ) while installing others packages (gam, dplyr,...) now.
The first time I tried to install Shiny package was the first time I saw this error. I had never seen it before.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you tried unistalling R and RStudio and installing them back?